# How to work around vcsrepo "duplicate declaration" evaluation error?

Tags: puppet

I am installing from github using puppet-vcsrepo. The code looks something like this:

```
class demo_class(
     $my_repo = undef,
     $my_tag  = undef,
){
    vcsrepo { "$my_repo",
        path     => "/home/user/$my_repo",
        source   => 'git@github.com:7yl4r/$my_repo.git',
        ensure   => latest,
        provider => git,
    }

    # then declare resources specific to my_tag
}
```

This works just fine when called only once, but I am iterating over a list and installing dependencies so this resource sometimes gets declared twice. I think this is roughly equivalent to the code below.

```
class {"demo_class":
    my_repo => test_repo,
    my_tag  => test_tag1,
}
class {"demo_class":
    my_repo => test_repo,
    my_tag  => test_tag2,
}
```

Doing this yields a server-side "Duplicate declaration" error because vcsrepo is trying to map the the same path twice. However, this is exactly the behavior I want: for both resources declared by `demo_class` to require the same repo in the same location. This is so that I can declare one or more resources using `demo_class` and be sure the repo given by `my_repo` (which may be common to multiple `my_tag`s) is there.

How can I modify this class so that I can call it twice without hitting an error?

Comment: Since you are not using `$myTag` in the `vcsrepo` resource, you are trying to do the same thing twice and Puppet's duplicate declaration error is correctly preventing you from potentially causing damage.

Comment: My use case is: I have two resources that require the same repo to be installed to the same location. If vcsrepo says "ensure repo A is in location B", what damage is risked by stating that twice?

Comment: Then you only have one `vcsrepo` resource that is required by both of those resources. I think you may be unaware that Puppet is a declarative language: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming

Comment: And your example is ambiguous about myTag.  Do you want testTag1 or testTag2?  This ambiguity causes the duplicate declaration error.  Read up on "resource like behaviour" to understand why redeclaring a class with different parameters is ambiguous https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/lang_classes.html#include-like-vs-resource-like

Comment: thanks for the link @bigtony. I think that my confusion may be due to not understanding the difference between resource-like and include-like behaviors. I think I might be using resources when I'm intending to do includes. I'll read up on this.

Comment: @MattSchuchard "Then you only have one vcsrepo resource that is required by both of those resources". Yes, I think that is exactly what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

I see the problem.

I reproduced the issue using this code:

```
  define my_vcs_repo ($myRepo, $myTag) {
    vcsrepo { "$myRepo-$myTag":
      path     => "/home/user/$myRepo",
      source   => "git@github.com:7yl4r/$myRepo.git",
      revision => $myTag,
      ensure   => latest,
      provider => git,
    }
  }

  $data = [
    {
      myRepo => testRepo,
      myTag  => testTag1,
    },
    {
      myRepo => testRepo,
      myTag  => testTag2,
    },
  ]

  $data.each |$i, $ref| {
    $myRepo = $ref['myRepo']
    $myTag  = $ref['myTag']
    my_vcs_repo { "$myRepo-$i":
      myRepo => $myRepo,
      myTag => $myTag,
    }
  }
```

That then results in:

```
     Puppet::PreformattedError:
       Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Cannot alias Vcsrepo[testRepo-testTag2] to ["/home/user/testRepo"] at /
Users/alexharvey/git/modules/foo/spec/fixtures/modules/foo/manifests/init.pp:3; resource ["Vcsrepo", "/home/user/testRepo"] already declared at /Users/alexharvey/git/modules/foo/spec/fixtures/modules/foo/
manifests/init.pp:3 at /Users/alexharvey/git/modules/foo/spec/fixtures/modules/foo/manifests/init.pp:3:5 at /Users/alexharvey/git/modules/foo/spec/fixtures/modules/foo/manifests/init.pp:26 on node alexs-macbook-pro.local
```

The problem is that you are asking Puppet to clone the same Git module to a directory but with two different tags checked out. That does not make sense.

The fix is that you need to specify a unique path in the vcsrepo path attribute, e.g.:

```
vcsrepo { "$myRepo-$myTag":
  path     => "/home/user/$myRepo-$myTag",
  source   => "git@github.com:7yl4r/$myRepo.git",
  revision => 'production',
  ensure   => latest,
  provider => git,
}
```

By the way, I notice you are using camelCase for your variables. Don't do that. Aside from the fact that it is not idiomatic for Puppet, there are things that will break in some versions of Puppet/Rspec puppet that I have seen.

Use `snake_case` for your variable names and class parameter names.

*Update*

The question has been edited, and it is now a question about how to declare the same `vcsrepo` in more than one class.

In general, try to refactor so that you do not need to do this in the first place. In other words, just move it out of this class and put it somewhere that is only expected to be declared once.

If you cannot do this for some reason, then you can also use [virtual resources](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/lang_virtual.html), which will allow you to declare it in multiple classes that will be declared on the same node.

To do that, you just have to rewrite what you have there as:

```
  @vcsrepo { $my_repo:
    path     => "/home/user/$my_repo",
    source   => "git@github.com:7yl4r/$my_repo.git",
    ensure   => latest,
    provider => git,
  }
  realize Vcsrepo[$my_repo]
```

Keep in mind that you will not be able to declare the class `demo_class` twice on the same node either. You would need to turn it into a defined type, as I did above.

It is mentioned in the comments below that you can also use `ensure_resource` and `ensure_resources`; see docs in [stdlib](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib).

Comment: "The problem is that you are asking Puppet to check out the same Git module with different tags in the same directory. That does not make sense." Sorry, to me this makes perfect sense. Imagine that I have two manifests which both want the same thing: "repo A installed in location B".

Comment: In retrospect my choice to use `my_tag` as a random variable name was terrible. I'm not referring to a tagged revision in the vcs. My_tag is just another variable I'm passing to the class to use for other things.

Comment: @7yl4r, it is simply not possible to have a Git module cloned to a directory with two different tags checked out, at the same time. Maybe your confusion is that you believe Puppet can check them out for you in sequence? No, that is not possible. You would need to use an orchestration tool like Ansible if that is your requirement.

Comment: @7yl4r What Alex is saying is that you cannot clone two different tags of a repo to the same path. I just googled to confirm that it is not possible.

Comment: Actually, now I realise that you have specified revision => production in both cases, to check out a branch, not a Git tag! Ok, now I am really confused about what you are trying to achieve. :)

Comment: Ah, I see you updated the question @7yl4r. Ok, that's a different question, and needs a different answer. :)

Comment: Sorry about that @AlexHarvey . I just edited the question to try to make it more clear. I think I'll find a solution after reading some more about resources vs includes in puppet.

Comment: @7yl4r If you want to group together resource declarations and declare that group more than once, then you should use a define.  You may wish to consider using the define $title variable for your tag or repo name.  See https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/lang_defined_types.html

Comment: Besides virtual resources, he could probably also use `ensure_resource`, which is arguably just as hacky. Redesign is still the best path forward here.